# Show that $[1/2, 1] \not\in \mathscr{T}_{1Y}$.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

**Background**

Let $X$ be the set of real numbers, and let $Y = (0,1]$.  If $\mathscr{T}_1$ is the standard topology on $\mathbb{R}$, and $\mathscr{T}_2$ is the [lower limit topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lower_limit_topology) on $\mathbb{R}$, then $Y$ as a subspace of $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{T}_1)$ has as topology
$$\mathscr{T}_{1Y}=\left\{(0,1] \cap \mathscr{O} \text{ }| \text{ } \mathscr{O} \in \mathscr{T}_1 \right\},$$
while $Y$ as a subspace of $(\mathbb{R}, \mathscr{T}_2)$ has as topology
$$\mathscr{T}_{2Y}=\left\{(0,1] \cap U \text{ }| \text{ } U \in \mathscr{T}_2 \right\}.$$

Note that
$$[1/2, 1] = (0, 1] \cap [1/2, 2) \in \mathscr{T}_{2Y}$$
since $Y=(0,1]$ and $[1/2, 2) \in \mathscr{T}_2$.

**Problem Statement**

> Show that $[1/2, 1] \not\in \mathscr{T}_{1Y}$.

**Attempt**

In $\mathscr{T}_{1Y}$:
$$(0,1] \cap \mathscr{O} = (0,1] \cap \left(\bigcup_{i \in I}(a_i,b_i)\right) = \bigcup_{i \in I}\bigg((0,1] \cap (a_i,b_i)\bigg)$$

But we have the following cases to consider:
$$(0,1] \cap (a_i,b_i) =
\begin{cases}
(0, 1] \text{  if  } a_1 \leq 0 \land 1 < b_1 \\
(0, b_i) \text{  if  } a_i \leq 0 \land b_i < 1 \\
(a_i, b_i) \text{  if  } 0 \leq a_i < b_i < 1 \\
(a_i, 1] \text{  if  } 0 \leq a_i \land b_i > 1 \\
\end{cases}
$$
Consequently, for each $i \in I$,
$$[1/2, 1] \not\in (0,1] \cap (a_i,b_i).$$
**Added August 18 2017:**  Should the last line be
$$[1/2, 1] \neq (0,1] \cap (a_i,b_i)?$$
Thus,
$$[1/2, 1] \notin \bigcup_{i \in I}\bigg((0,1] \cap (a_i,b_i)\bigg) = \mathscr{T}_{1Y}.$$

**Question**

> Is this proof *correct*?  Is it also *adequate*?

Comment: It is not correct. You want to show that $[1/2,1]$ is not equal to the given union. You do not want to show it isn't an element of the union. As a hint: In order for $1/2$ to be an element of such a union, what can we say about some component interval?

Comment: @CameronBuie, so in order for $1/2$ to be an element of such a union, some component interval must contain $1/2$?

Comment: @MariosGretsas, my apologies, but I don't follow.  Do you mean the first case for $(0,1] \cap (a_i,b_i)$?

Comment: I will post an answer and you can evaluate,..I hope it is correct.

Comment: Okay, @MariosGretsas.  Thank you!

Comment: @ArchimedesPlutonium: That's exactly the idea. What could such a component look like? Are any such components contained (as a subset) in $[1/2,1]$?

Comment: @CameronBuie, from Marios's example in his answer, we have
$$[1/2, 1] = (0, 1] \cap (1/3, 2).$$
But now I am confused because Marios claims that this example implies that $[1/2, 1] \in \mathscr{T}_{1Y}$ and *not the other way around*.

Comment: Sadly, Marios's answer is incorrect.

Comment: Indeed my answer is incorrect..@ArchimedesPlutonium..im sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @CameronBuie, can you please pinpoint the exact part in my solution that is incorrect?  Is my correction dated **August 18 2017** not enough to mend the error in that part (if we are thinking about the same part)?

Comment: @Archimedes: That fixes one issue. Younstill have the same issue on the next line, but justifying the correction will rtake a bit more work. See if you can answer the questions I asked most recently.

Comment: Okay will do, @CameronBuie.

Comment: @ArchimedesPlutonium...i posted another answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assume that there is a set $O \in \mathcal{T}_1$ such that $O \cap (0,1]=[\frac{1}{2},1]$

Thus $\frac{1}{2} \in O$ and $O$ is open thus exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $(\frac{1}{2} -\epsilon,\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon) \subseteq O$ and

Note that $(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon,\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon) \cap (0,1] \subseteq O \cap (0,1].$

> From this we see that we cannot have $\epsilon>1/2$ because if $\epsilon> \frac{1}{2}$ then $\frac{1}{2}- \epsilon=c<0$
>
> Thus $(c,\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon) \cap(0,1]=(0,1] \subseteq [\frac{1}{2},1]$  which is a contradiction.

So we have that $\epsilon< \frac{1}{2}$ and $$(\frac{1}{2}- \epsilon,\frac{1}{2}+ \epsilon)=(\frac{1}{2}-\epsilon,\frac{1}{2}+\epsilon) \cap (0,1] \subseteq O \cap (0,1]=[\frac{1}{2},1]$$

Therefore $$\frac{1}{2}- \frac{\epsilon}{2} \in [\frac{1}{2},1]$$ which is a contradiction

Comment: This looks correct, @MariosGretsas.  I will wait until tomorrow for the final verdict.

Comment: ok yes you can wait..im sorry for the confusion before..my mind just stuck and  i couldn't see that the intersection was wrong..I hope this time i'm correct